# Updating Products website

Tags: magento-1.8

I have implemented the code to update existing products so that they get added to the new store website I have created.

```
    $websiteIds = array(1, 2);
    $skus = 'sku1, sku2';

    $skuArray = explode(',', $skus);

    $productIds = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('find_in_set' => $skuArray))
            ->getAllIds();

    Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->addProducts($websiteIds, $productIds);
```

The code works well and adds these products to the other website too, but when the product is viewed, it does not display the Buy Now option, now when I Reindexed the URLs then it started displaying the Buy Now. Is it something I can do programatically when updating the products, because I will be having huge products on my live website and Indexing will also take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$websiteIds = array(1, 2);
$skus = 'sku1,sku2,sku3';
$skuArray = explode(',', $skus);
foreach($skuArray as $sku) {
    $product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($sku);
    if($product->getId()) {
        $product->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this one, but there are huge number of products to be updated, and I am not going to update all products, say 75% of the products, if I do this all using Admin, it will only keep loading

Comment: If you see the code I have provided, it does the same as you have mentioned

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to find some other way too. I am trying to skip the looping thing.